# XSLT modify based on condition in xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have below input, I have to update the `<price>` of `<orderitem>` with `<name>` = `Desktop` with the `<price>` of another `<orderitem>` (present anywhere in the xml) which has same value of `<associationid>` as its `<objectid>`.

Here for example, i have `<associationid>` as 2 for `Desktop`, now I look for `<objectid>` with value as 2 and get its price and update it here. Sample output below.

Kindly let me know the approach to solve such problems involving traversing, I am new to XSL and trying to refer the XSLT cook book and SO, but not getting proper reference. Thanks.

```
<listoforders>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120ass</price>
        <associationid>2</associationid>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>Desktop2</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>Desktop3</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130obj1</price>
            <objectid>1</objectid>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>laptop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120</price>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>laptop2</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>laptop3</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130obj2</price>
            <objectid>2</objectid>
        </Orderitem>
    </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

Output

```
<listoforders>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>130obj2</price>
        <associationid>2</associationid>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>Desktop2</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>Desktop3</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130obj1</price>
            <objectid>1</objectid>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>laptop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120</price>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>laptop2</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130</price>
        </Orderitem>
        <Orderitem>
            <name>laptop3</name>
            <place>NZ</place>
            <price>130obj2</price>
            <objectid>2</objectid>
        </Orderitem>
    </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="price[../name='Desktop']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="price[//objectid=.//associationid]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to resolve cross-references:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="ord" match="Orderitem" use="objectid" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price[../name='Desktop']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('ord', ../associationid)/price"/>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what is the difference

Comment: Its shorter and simpler  - and I already wrote it before you posted yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use key for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:key name="keyitem" match="price" use="../objectid"/>

        <!-- Identity Transformation -->
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="price[../name eq 'Desktop'][../associationid]">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="../associationid"/>
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('keyitem',$id)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed three things in your XSLT:

1. In the `xsl:copy-of`, you are currently not traversing through all the prices like you intended, for that you need to use `//price`.
2. In the condition, you want to test the element `objectid` that belongs to the price, so you should use `../objectid` rather than `//objectid`.
3. Therefor, in the condition you implicitly "leave" the context of the desktop price element, so you no longer have direct access to `.//associationid`. However, you can use the `current()` function to refer to the object (Thanks [michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k))

This XSLT produces the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="price[../name='Desktop']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//price[../objectid=current()/../associationid]"/>         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another possibility would be to use a variable to store the id for later comparison.

```
<xsl:template match="price[../name='Desktop']">
    <xsl:variable name="var.associationid" select="../associationid"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//price[../objectid=$var.associationid]"/>         
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is what the `current()` function is for. Still, using a key is both more elegant and more efficient.